# sunspot 1.10 - solr_home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, rake, sunspot-rails

I'm using sunspot 1.1.0 , and I tried setting the solr_home in sunspot.yml . when I fire the solr it doesn't take solr_home into account.
Is there another way to start solr "rake sunspot:solr:start" and pass in the solr_home ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a flag for that (-s SOLR_HOME) (or --solr_home=SOLR_HOME)

```
rake sunspot:solr:start -s SOLR_HOME
```